# Can you keep the connection open between invocations of `aws s3` CLI?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

SSH has [a useful opt-in feature](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/speeding-up-ssh-session-creation/) that allows you to reuse a connection between invocations:

```
ssh host 'echo example' # this opens the connection to host, and leaves it open
ssh host 'echo example2' # this reuses the connection from the previous command
```

Is there something similar for the AWS S3 command-line interface?  For example:

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucketname/example1 s3://bucketname/example2
aws s3 mv s3://bucketname/example3 s3://bucketname/example4
```

It would be great if the first command would open a connection, and leave it open for the second to take advantage of it. This would speed up AWS S3 CLI tremendously when running a ton of small commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. You could always use `boto3` directly, the Python SDK, or in fact any of the SDKs for any of the supported languages. It would allow you to persist a connection, but the CLI does not support that sort of thing.

Comment: Correct. It is the Python SDK. You could use any of the SDKs though.